# Simple NodeJS RESTful API with post method and no database involved

Tags: javascript

Im very new to nodejs ive used an exmaple to write simple REST app, this is using GET method but im trying to use POST method with --data, for example

```
curl -X POST --data 'bla' http://localhost:port
```

i want it to return repsone "blabla"
im trying to see all kinds of exmaple but lots of them using databases and on this simple app i dont want any database involved,
appriciate if anyone can guide me or point me to a good example

**edit

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(new Date(), req.url, req.method)
    next()
})

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       if (req.body.data == 'bla'){
          res.send("blabla")
}

    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})


app.listen(3000)
```

it works without the "if" part, i must be missing something small here...

Comment: Well, recommendations are off-topic, so your question will likely be closed,  but you can always have a look at [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html), probably the most popular Nodejs framework out there

Comment: @JeremyThille I would recommend to check out Express as well. Here is an example with all methods and most common features (middleware, 404, 500) for express: https://gist.github.com/LarsFlieger/2a9859270419be5a4093dd63194a2c2c